# Rotating and placing an image via CSS not working for 270 degrees

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'd like to be able to rotate an image by 90 degrees each time i click a button. I also want it to be "pinned" to the top left corner of the containing DIV.

My code seems to work for all except 270, where it rotates correctly but doesnt position correctly.

I can "fix" the position on image-by-image basis by tweaking the translate, but i'd prefer a generic way. I admit I dont know much about 2D transforms so if anyone can explain, i'd be thankful!

Please find below a simple abstraction of my problem:

**Code:**

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" id="myrotate">[ rotate ]</a>
<div style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <img id="myimage" src="http://images.domain.com.au/img/Agencys/16067/logo_16067.GIF" style="border: 3px solid silver;" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.rot0 {
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.rot90 {
  transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.rot180 {
  transform:rotate(180deg);  
}

.rot270 {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateY(-148%);
    transform-origin: right top;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#myrotate").click(
  function(e) {
    var img = $("#myimage");
    if (img.hasClass("rot0"))
      img.removeClass("rot0").addClass("rot90");
    else if (img.hasClass("rot90"))
      img.removeClass("rot90").addClass("rot180");
    else if (img.hasClass("rot180"))
      img.removeClass("rot180").addClass("rot270");
    else if (img.hasClass("rot270"))
      img.removeClass("rot270").addClass("rot0");
    else
      img.addClass("rot90");
  }
);
```

**MVCE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/d3g0x72t/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you actually want:

```
.rot270 {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

We need to translateX, not Y here. Updated fiddle:

```js
$("#myrotate").click(
  function(e) {
    var img = $("#myimage");
    if (img.hasClass("rot0"))
      img.removeClass("rot0").addClass("rot90");
    else if (img.hasClass("rot90"))
      img.removeClass("rot90").addClass("rot180");
    else if (img.hasClass("rot180"))
      img.removeClass("rot180").addClass("rot270");
    else if (img.hasClass("rot270"))
      img.removeClass("rot270").addClass("rot0");
    else
      img.addClass("rot90");
  }
);
//http://images.domain.com.au/img/Agencys/16067/logo_16067.GIF
//http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/mediawiki/a/a9/Example.jpg
```

```css
.rot0 {
  transform-origin: left top;
}

.rot90 {
  transform: translateY(-100%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
}

.rot180 {
  transform:rotate(180deg);  
}

.rot270 {
  transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin: left top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="myrotate">[ rotate ]</a>
<div style="border: 1px solid red;">
  <img id="myimage" src="http://images.domain.com.au/img/Agencys/16067/logo_16067.GIF" style="border: 3px solid silver;" />
</div>
```